# Generating Dynamic Table Content in C#

Tags: arrays, dynamic, html-table, repeater

I'm having a bit of a challenge to create the following:

I need to generate a number of fixed sized tables of 2 columns and 4 rows in ASP.NET based on an xml content. So my html container is a multiple of table with a fixed sized 2 columns by 4 rows. In each table, each column will hold an [item] from the xml, where the top cell in the column is the [category] tag, and the 3 cells underneath holds the [make#] tags; so one for each [make#] for a total of 4 rows in the column. So a Table can hold 2 [item] ; one for each column.

Assuming my source is from an XML file:

```
<items>
<item>
<category>Cat 1</category>
<make1>101</make1>
<make2>102</make2>
<make3>103</make3>
</item>
<item>
<category>Cat 2</category>
<make1>201</make1>
<make2>202</make2>
<make3>203</make3>
</item>
<item>
<category>Cat 3</category>
<make1>301</make1>
<make2>302</make2>
<make3>303</make3>
</item>
<item>
<category>Cat 4</category>
<make1>401</make1>
<make2></make2>
<make3></make3>
</item>
<item>
<category>Cat 5</category>
<make1>501</make1>
<make2>502</make2>
<make3</make3>
</item>
</items>
```

and my desired output for the 5 categories where each category can have up to 3 items underneath in html is:

```
<table> 
<tr> <td>Cat 1</td> <td>Cat 2</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>101</td> <td>201</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>102</td> <td>202</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>103</td> <td>203</td> </tr> 
</table>
<table> 
<tr> <td>Cat 3</td> <td>Cat 4</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>301</td> <td>401</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>302</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>303</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
</table>
<table> 
<tr> <td>Cat 5</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>501</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>502</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
<tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
</table>
```

How would I achieve this?

Note I need tables because I'm using a carousel with a hard coded carousel with that structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion I think we came to the conclusion that the repeater method is not the best route to take. The basic problem here is how to input two entities side-by-side. There is an asp.net control built for this: the DataList.

With the DataList, you can set the maximum number of items to repeat as well as the direction to repeat the items (Horizontal / Vertical).

So, with that, you will want to add the following DataList code to your aspx page:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <HeaderTemplate>Items</HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# XPath("category")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# XPath("make1")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# XPath("make2")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# XPath("make3")%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

The key here is that each item's data is bound in the `<ItemTemplate>`. Then the DataList itself takes care of arranging each item according to the flags `RepeatColumns="2"` and `RepeatDirection="Horizontal"`.

Some quick `<asp:XmlDataSource>` magic:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    XPath="//items/item">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Where `XPath="//items/item"` points the XmlDataSource to the location of each entity in the xml. This is bound to the DataList with the following tag on the DataList itself: `DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1"`

On the code-behind file I cheated and just fed the XML as a string:

> ```
>   this.XmlDataSource1.Data = @"<items>
>                                   <item>
>                                       <category>Cat 1</category>
>                                       <make1>101</make1>
>                                       <make2>102</make2>
>                                       <make3>103</make3>
>                                   </item>
>                                   <item>
>                                       <category>Cat 2</category>
>                                       <make1>201</make1>
>                                       <make2>202</make2>
>                                       <make3>203</make3>
>                                   </item>
>                                   <item>
>                                       <category>Cat 3</category>
>                                       <make1>301</make1>
>                                       <make2>302</make2>
>                                       <make3>303</make3>
>                                   </item>
>                                   <item>
>                                       <category>Cat 4</category>
>                                       <make1>401</make1>
>                                       <make2></make2>
>                                       <make3></make3>
>                                   </item>
>                                   <item>
>                                       <category>Cat 5</category>
>                                       <make1>501</make1>
>                                       <make2>502</make2>
>                                       <make3></make3>
>                                   </item>
>                                   </items>";
> ```

And she works!

BTW, I'll never forgive you for the missing ">" in the XML of your original post. Drove me nuts finding it. :)

Now, granted that ideally the best method to do all this is deserializing the xml into .NET classes and binding everything the proper way (ie: code-behind binding of data, etc), but the general idea is there.

**Regarding OP comment about nested table issue:**

The GridList has a property called RepeatLayout. Setting this property to RepeatLayout.Flow will use other elements rather than tables. From MSDN:

> Items are displayed without a table structure. Rendered markup consists of a span element and items are separated by br elements. [Layouts for each enum here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatlayout.aspx#Y0)

Also, this article discusses the differences between the DataGrid, DataList and Repeater [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479015.aspx)

**OLD ANSWER:**

I'm thinking along the lines of a Usercontrol that accepts two item entities as parameters.

So if you have a class called Item:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Category{get;set;}
    public List<string> Makes { get; set; }
}
```

And your UserControl looks like this:
(ASPX)

```
<table> 
<tr>
    <td><asp:Label ID="lblCategory1" runat="server" /></td>
    <td><asp:Label ID="lblCategory2" runat="server" /></td>
</tr> 
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMakes" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate><tr></tr></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMake1" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMake2" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate></tr><tr></SeparatorTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tr>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

and like this on the .cs page:

```
private Item Item2;

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    this.rptMakes.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(rptMakes_ItemDataBound);
    base.OnInit(e);
}

void rptMakes_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblMake1")).Text = e.Item.DataItem.ToString();
        if (this.Item2 != null)
        {
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblMake2")).Text = this.Item2.Makes[e.Item.ItemIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblMake2")).Text = "&nbsp;";
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
public void Populate(Item item1, Item item2)
{
    this.lblCategory1.Text = item1.Category;
    if (item2 != null)
    {
        this.lblCategory2.Text = item2.Category;
    }
    else
    {
        this.lblCategory2.Text = "&nbsp;";
    }
    this.Item2 = item2;
    this.rptMakes.DataSource = item1.Makes;
    this.rptMakes.DataBind();
}
```

From there it is just a matter of iterating over the original list of Item entities on your aspx page and passing out every two entities to a UC.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your suggestion but i can't seem to see how it generated the output i need.

Comment: Also, when is Populate called? I'm guessing this is called within a loop that reads from the xml (in fact a webservice which i have dumped the content in a DataSet) to a class item to Populate() which triggers the actual generation of the repeater items, right... Sorry i'm a bit of a noob just coming from conventional classic html merge ... this sounds too complicated ... surely there must be a qcuiker way, right?... At this point, i've tried using a nested repeater... outer repeater to generate for each table tags and inner repeater for the content of the parent table... but no success :(

Comment: Believe me, if you have already dealt with nested repeaters then this is not too complicated :) The challenge here is that you want to iterate over a two entities which would require vertical output (Category, Make1 .. MakeN) but you want the output to be horizontal (two columns side by side). In answer to your question, you would call the Populate method from the main .aspx page. Do you want me to give you some sample code that would show the binding?

Comment: That would be great because i can't see the iteration on item entities... Tell me... is this unconventional what i'm doing? I mean given that i can't change my webservice that returns me this xml structure... and that I need to display the fixed size table ( so 2 items at a time in this case...is this the best  ( efficient and shortest) approach?

Comment: Sorry have not been able to reply, very busy at work today. Your question got me to rethink the whole issue. We started down the repeater path, but on second-thought that was a mistake. There is a control called the DataList that is perfect for what you are trying to do. It has a property called `RepeatColumns` which, you guessed it, determines how many columns to output for each row. So if you set it to 2, it will display your data how you want. Also, don't forget to set `RepeatDirection` to Horizontal. This should get you on your way, if you have any problems I'll be back tomorrow.Good luck.

Comment: I'm still lost... i still can't see how this will create a table for each 2 record... can you post some code please?

Comment: I went ahead and updated the answer with the code sample you wanted. Did this clear things up a bit?

Comment: Not exactly what i needed but close enough... i learn something new as well abotu datalist...will definitely come in handy... the only downside is that this will create a nested table of items...other than that it works thanks!

Comment: There's a property for that :) RepeatLayout=Flow. See my edits in answer.